# In flutter having this problem "A problem occurred configuring project ':video_player_android'. "

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, pubspec.yaml

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':video_player_android'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\ibrahim42386\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\video_player_android-2.4.9\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':video_player_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':video_player_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

But I did not even use this library in my project. Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: test
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.1.0+2

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  get: ^4.6.5
  get_storage:
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.0.0+2
  intl: ^0.17.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  google_fonts: ^4.0.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.0
  http: ^0.13.5
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.0
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.10.3
  image_picker: ^1.0.1


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/images/logo.jpeg"
  android: true
  ios: true
  min_sdk_android: 21
```

Comment: Have you solve this issue?I am also facing the same issue